# Frontrun Bot for the Binance Smart Chain

Tags: performance, validation, transactions, bots, block

I've built a frontrun bot for BSC, but I am really disappointed with the result..

Sometimes the bot works, sometimes it doesnt.

Example:

1. Transaction is pending (5gwei) (Block 1000)
2. My Bot will send his transaction with 6gwei

I also want my transaction to be in block 1000
And it does work

But sometimes my transcation will be mined in block 1001

How can I avoid this?

Regards!

Comment: send your transaction in block 999 :) BSC is very fast

Comment: explain how....

Comment: Buy a surplus time machine on eBay

Comment: Hey, did you come out with a solution eventually?